# How to remove sub-items from a Structure navigation item?

Tags: structure, navigation

I am completely new to Expression Engine and I am trying to reverse engineer a site that someone else built. From what I understand, there is a plugin called "Structure" which controls the main navigation of the site.

```
{exp:ce_cache:escape}
    {exp:ce_cache:it:nested id="topnav" global="no" seconds="3600"}
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="2" max_depth="2" add_unique_ids="yes" css_class="topnav" css_id="none" current_class="current" include="3|4|5|17|18" exclude="10"}
    {/exp:ce_cache:it:nested}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape}
```

There is a navigation item which contains too many sub-items (which results in a really long drop-down), so my task is to hide the sub-items while keeping the page that they link to. I went to the "Structure" section of admin and only found the ability to delete pages.

How can I hide the drop-down for this particular nav item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the Structure plugin does not provide a way of controlling the depth of an individual navigation item, so I came up with a hack to address this issue. By using a little bit of Javascript, I am removing the subnav/dropdown `<ul>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ul = document.getElementById('my-nav-item').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  ul.parentNode.removeChild(ul);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you, you would like to hide all the subitems and keep the main navigation unchanged? This can be done by changing show_depth="2" to show_depth="0". That way all you will see is the main navigation and there will no longer be a dropdown for the subitems.

```
{exp:ce_cache:escape}
    {exp:ce_cache:it:nested id="topnav" global="no" seconds="3600"}
        {exp:structure:nav start_from="/" show_depth="0" max_depth="2" add_unique_ids="yes" css_class="topnav" css_id="none" current_class="current" include="3|4|5|17|18" exclude="10|#|#|#|#"}
    {/exp:ce_cache:it:nested}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would affect all the nav items. I only want to hide one particular drop down (ID #17) and keep the rest.

Comment: In order to do that you need to remove it from include="3|4|5|17|18" and move it to exclude="10|17". Is #17 the parent nav for subpages? If so just go into the CP and get the ID's for the subpages and just add those to the **exclude**.

Comment: But wouldn't that remove 17 from the nav entirely? I just want to hide its children.

Comment: Place the subpages of #17 exclude tag, once you do that the dropdown will no longer appear and you will be able to navigate without issue.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me. If ever an admin adds a new page, the template will have to be updated too. I need a dynamic solution, not something hard coded.